# Visual Studio 2010 Find and Replace dialog on dual monitors is whacked

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is anyone else having issues with the find and replace dialog in Visual Studio 2010?

For as many improvements that have been made for multi monitor support is VS, this is making me crazy.

Whenever I open up the *Find and Replace* dialog in VS 2010, it often straddles the two monitors.  The other dialogs, like *Navigate To* seem to always work.

Is this making anyone else go a little batty, or is it just me?

Anyone have a fix?  *Find and Replace* VS extension?

**Update:**
There is a hotfix out for this issue now (KB2268081):
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads

Comment: Not only that, each time it is opened, it is a little bit bigger than the last time it was closed.

Comment: I tried to edit the title to say "on" instead of "no" since obviously "no" was a typo.  The title says exactly the opposite of what it means.  Anyone know why SO pretends to accept such edits?

Comment: Hah.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: So that's why I sometimes notice my Find/Replace is huge.

Comment: Aha - And I thought it was just me.

Comment: Jeez...  it's now 7 years later, we're onto Visual Studio 2017, and the same issue is there.  I have my laptop display plus 2 monitors, and almost always, the Find dialog appears 2 screens away from the monitor showing VS2017.  Just dreadful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I noticed the same, it can get pretty annoying.

Based on feedback in Microsoft Connect this is a known issue that should be fixed for VS 2010 SP1.

Source:([1](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/561911/find-and-replace-dialog-expanded-to-both-monitors-in-multi-monitor-setup),[2](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/562318/findandreplace-andhide))

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I didn't think to check Connect.  At least it's a known issue...

Answer (score 6):

The Find and Replace dialog is now dockable. Dock it with the Properties window, as a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use Actual Window Manager (http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/) to manage The Find and Replace dialog. Just create a specific rule to save size and position of the dialog and The Find and Replace dialog will appear at the same plase as you closed it last time.

Answer (score 1):

Open Extension Manager - VS2010,
Download and install 2 extensions of the most downloads.
And restart your VS, you will find that Find and replace box will just like VS2012