# Visual Studio Dual Monitor Layout : Watch/Debug Window keeps Popping on Left Screen

Tags: visual-studio

Every Time I launch a Debug Session VS 2010 pops the Watch/Debug Windows on the left Screen. 
I then move it manually to the Right One. After ending the session, going back to code, and relaunching a debug session, that damned Watch window pops on the left again. 
It turns me crazy ! 
Why isn't VS memorizing where I have put that window ???

Comment: I despise this behavior. Its so infuriating to keep losing concentration to re-position rogue windows.

Comment: Still broken. (chars to meet limit)

Answer (score 0):

Do you stop debug session with `Shift+F5` or by quitting application which is being debugged? VS seems to forget window positions if debugging process was stopped by `Shift+F5`.

Comment: that is the same as `Shift+F5`. Try closing the application at least one time. If you're creating a web-project or smth else that cannot be `closed` then try it with empty windows app.

Comment: It's a winform App. I did close the form but still popping in the wrong screen :-(

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution I found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939238/how-to-save-the-vs-window-layout-for-single-extended-multiple-screen). Did not work.
Seems like it's the exact same problem as with the find dialog (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970754/visual-studio-2010-find-and-replace-dialog-on-dual-monitors-is-whacked) post)

Ended-up docking the heck out of the Watch/debug window into a more "stable" panel (Class view in my case).

This still looks like an annoying known bug in VS 2010. This sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio 2010 has at least 3 screen modes.

- Normal
- Full
- Debug

You should export the window settings after entering into the desired screen mode(in your case, debug).

Steps

1. Start 'debug' your project
2. Move the desired windows(watch/debug) to the 2nd monitor on right
3. Goto Tools>Import and Export Settings>Export selected environment settings>General Settings>Window Layouts and export it into a file.
4. Load the settings by using the import settings in the same window

Visual studio would remember your settings and would move the window to the 2nd monitor on the right, whenever you enter 'debug' mode.

As a tip, it is a great idea to create macros to load window settings and to assign keystrokes to switch between window modes, depending on the kind  of development you are on.

code to create a macro to import a vssetting file:
 DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings", "-import:Path to VSSetting File")